# how to tell react to run framer motion unmount animate when re-render

Tags: reactjs, animation, framer-motion

I'm creating a sidebar which contains some items and some of the items contain sub-items
here is my demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-sidebar-effect-mfkpsl?file=/src/SidebarListItem.jsx

now the opacity and blur animation only runs when I hover Home and then About/Contact (from sub-items container -> non-(subitems container) or vice versa)

what I want to acheive is run the animation even when I switch from About to Contact (About and Contact both contain sub-items)

if 2 items also contains sub-item it won't trigger unmount of the sub-list how I could do it?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using this `motion.ul` to contain the submenu for the hovered section:

```
<motion.ul
  variants={subMenuVariant}
  className="absolute top-0 right-0 pr-10 translate-x-[115%]"
>
  {navLinks
    .filter((item) => item.link === currentHover)[0]
    .sublinks.map((link, i) => (
      <li
        key={i}
        className="py-1.5 text-[1.8rem] select-none cursor-pointer"
      >
        {link}
      </li>
    ))}
</motion.ul>
```

Since only the child elements are changing (the `li`s), Framer treats the `ul` as the same unchanging container element. So it doesn't animate in and out as the content changes.

You need to set a unique `key` on the container element (`motion.ul`) so Framer knows the element changed. Otherwise it thinks you intend that element to remain the same and it won't trigger the animation.

You can use your `currentHover` variable since that value changes when your hover target changes:

```
<motion.ul
    key={currentHover}
    variants={subMenuVariant}
    className="absolute top-0 right-0 pr-10 translate-x-[115%]"
>
```

Comment: Hi Cadin, sorry for my late reply! Thanks for the detail reply and it works!
So the main concept of this is I have to let Framer-motion know there is something changed by passing state to key props of the element. 
Do I understand it right? 
Again thanks a lot!